# Jsoup - CSS Query selector issue (?)

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I´m with an odd issue here, I´ve been using **Jsoup 1.7.2** for a while, with no issues, only now, when I try to retrieve the main headlines from this website: *www.jornaldamarinha.pt*, using this code:

```java
// Connecting...
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.jornaldamarinha.pt")
                    .timeout(0)
                    .get();

// "*[class*=zincontent-wrap]" in "Jsoup idiom", means:  
// Select all tags that contains classes with "zincontent-wrap" on its name.
Elements elems = doc.select("*[class*=zincontent-wrap]"); // Retrieves 0 results!

int t = elems.size();
Log.w("INFO", "Total Headlines: " + t);

// Loop trought all retrieved headlines:
for (Element e : elems) {
   String headline = e.select("a").text().toString();
   Log.w("HEADLINE", headline);
};
```

It fails!... Retrieves 0 results. *(Should retrieve ~8)*

**The chances are that the issue is caused by:**

1. Aliens... *(Similar to androids, but uglier...)*
2. Website encoding. *(I tried to encode incoming HTML with ISO-8859-15, to handle portuguese special characters, but the issue remains)*
3. Mal-formatted incoming HTML. *(I doubt this could be the issue, since the selector works fine on "Try jsoup online webpage", and Jsoup usually handles broken HTML very well)*
4. The use of the minus symbol in the class name ("-") is messing with Jsoup. *(Seems, to me, to be the main (or at least, one) cause of the issue)*
5. Something else... *(Very probably!)*

---

**BUT**... at http://try.jsoup.org if I fetch the URL: http://www.jornaldamarinha.pt using this CSS Query:

```
*[class*=zincontent-wrap]
```

Everything works just great, there! *(Retrieves all the ~8 correct results!)*

---

**SO**... to resume, all I need is to do exactly what that webpage does, but using code.

THANKS, in advance, for any light or workaround, about this! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION!...** After all, everything in the above code, was working correctly, as I suspected, except... That CSS Query breaks on Android´s "default user agent". I just figured that setting "**userAgent**" to Jsoup´s connection method is **VERY** important! So, I´ve edited my code on the following way, and... Works like a charm now !! *(Exactly with same results, as in http://try.jsoup.org webpage)*

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.jornaldamarinha.pt")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0")
                    .timeout(0)
                    .get();
```

Hope this helps anyone else too! :)