# jsoup: How to extract correct data from this website

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to extract data from a Spanish dictionary using jsoup.  Essentially, the user will input words he wants to define as command line arguments and the program will return a formatted list of definitions.  Here is what I have done so far:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] urls = new String[args.length];
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            urls[i] = "http://www.diccionarios.com/detalle.php?palabra="
                + args[i]
                + "&Buscar.x=0&Buscar.y=0&Buscar=submit&dicc_100=on&dicc_100=on";
            try{
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urls[i]).get();
                Elements htmly = doc.getElementsByTag("html");
                String untokenized = htmly.text();

                System.out.println(untokenized);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("EXCEPTION: Word is probably not in this dictionary.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That url array gives the correct urls where the information for the definition is.

Now, what I'm expecting to be returned is what you would get if you went to the try.jsoup website and used (for example)  this : http://www.diccionarios.com/detalle.php?palabra=libro&Buscar.x=0&Buscar.y=0&Buscar=submit&dicc_100=on&dicc_100=on 
as the link and typed in html as the CSS Query.  I need that data so I can tokenize the definition from that.

So I guess my question is, what method would I use to obtain the same data that you can see on the try.jsoup website.  Thanks a lot!

Edit:  This is about interpreting the data from the url.  The end result data I want (in this example) is "Conjunto de hojas escritas unidas o cosidas por uno de sus lados y cubiertas por tapas de cartón u otro material."  That is the definition on the website.  However, I noticed that on that try.jsoup website that if I put the html text in the CSS Query box then the result was a huge bunch of text.  My assumption was that the following 2 lines of code would capture this huge bunch of text and save it as a string:

```
Elements htmly = doc.getElementsByTag("html");
String untokenized = htmly.text();
```

However, the output for when I print untokenized is instead this: "Usuario Clave ¿Olvidaste tu clave? Condiciones Privacidad Versión completa © 2011 Larousse Editorial, SL."  So my question is, how to I obtain the string data for that huge bunch of text found on the try.jsoup website?

EDIT:  I followed the advice of the question here: [Jsoup - CSS Query selector issue (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060335/jsoup-css-query-selector-issue) and it worked great.

Comment: What do you want to obtain from the website that you have linked?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you successful in getting the html via the ```Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urls[i]).get();``` call? So is this about fetching the url or about interpreting the result?